# How to get timestamp in milliseconds for two weeks back from the current date in C++?

Tags: c++, timestamp, milliseconds

I need to calculate timestamp in milliseconds for two weeks old date from the current date.

As of now this is the way I am calculating current timestamp in milliseconds -

```
struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
uint64_t current_ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000; //get current timestamp in milliseconds
```

Now I am not sure how do I get the timestamp in milliseconds for two weeks back from the current date? I am interested in making a function which returns me the timestamp in milliseconds for two weeks back from the current date.

I recently started working with C++ so not sure what is the right way to check out a timestamp in milliseconds for two weeks old. I will be running this code on Ubuntu 12.04.

**Update:-**

Below is the code I have -

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto twoWeeks = std::chrono::hours(24 * 14);
    auto lastTwoWeeks = now - twoWeeks;

    auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>\
                    (lastTwoWeeks.time_since_epoch()).count();
    std::cout << "Time stamp in milliseconds since UNIX epoch start: "\
              << millis << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just subtract 1209600000?

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, following may help:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto twoWeeks = std::chrono::hours(24 * 14);
    auto lastTwoWeeks = now - twoWeeks;

    // display time_point:
    std::time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(lastTwoWeeks);
    std::cout << "last Two Weeks is: " << ctime(&tt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what happens if the time is changed in the previous two weeks?  Does chronos 'fix' the timestamp captured 2 or more weeks ago?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: I don't understand your question. `now` returns a fixed time point based on OS. `ctime` returns a readable local date. the rest is pure arithmetic and computation.

Comment: Let me try again.  A timestamp set 1.7 weeks ago will get a value, call it 27.  If the wall clock changes, as in an automatic time update from its clock server, or dst starting or ending, does that time stamp (captured 1.7 weeks ago) change to a (not-27) value ?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: `now` returns basically the number of seconds since epoch (`1970`), so as I understand your question, no, changing the date of the OS doesn't change the result of the previous calls.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Jarod42's answer, if you want to get the time stamp since the epoch start (1/1/1970) in milliseconds, append the following two lines to @Jarod42's code:

```
auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>\
                (lastTwoWeeks.time_since_epoch()).count();
std::cout << "Time stamp in milliseconds since UNIX epoch start: "\
          << millis << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip. I have updated the question with the code I am going to use. Does that look right to you in which I am using your epoch suggestion as well?

Comment: @user2809564 if you want to compute how many milliseconds passed between 1/1/1970 and two weeks ago, then yes, the code is correct.

Comment: Thanks makes sense now. I guess I don't have C++11 portability as of now in my environment. Is there any other way to write this thing out?